# Can we conclude that $n = m^2$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ be such that for every prime $p$, the following holds: $$p \mid n \implies p^2 \mid n$$
Can we conclude that $n = m^2$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$?

How can I prove or disprove this, I'm not sure where to begin. Thanks.

Comment: You can only deduce your number is divisible by a square.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Try $n=8$. $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $